# Scrapy returning numbers and letters instead of "?" for href value

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a web forum using Scrapy for the href link info and when I do so, I get the href link with many letters and numbers where the question mark should be.

This is a sample of the html document that I am scraping:

```
<a href="showthread.php?t=2755261" id="thread_title_2676278"></a>
```

I am scraping the html data for the href link using the following code:

```
response.xpath('.//*[contains(@id, "thread_title")]/@href').extract()
```

When I run this, I get the following results:

```
[u'showthread.php?s=f969fe6ed424b22d8fddf605a9effe90&t=2676278']
```

What should be returned is:

```
[u'showthread.php?t=2676278']
```

I have ran other tests scraping for href data with question marks elsewhere in the document and I also get the "**s=f969fe6ed424b22d8fddf605a9effe90&**" returned.

Why am I getting this data returned with the "**s=f969fe6ed424b22d8fddf605a9effe90&**" instead of just the question mark?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be a session ID that you're getting because your scraper can't deal with cookies

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have disabled cookies in "settings.py" however I am still getting this string in all of my links with "?"s in them.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why. The forum you're scraping detects that your scraper can't handle cookies (which is the usual way of storing that long `s` value, it is present in the browser too but invisible, hidden away in the cookie) so it adds them to the URL.

Comment: So do I need to adjust my spider to handle the cookies, or is there no way to get rid of this string in the url besides adding code to remove it from the returned value?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be enabling cookies, yeah.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem. If it works let me know, I can post an answer for future generations

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the site I am scraping from uses a unique identifier in order to more accurately update the number of views per the thread. I was not able to return scraped data without a unique id, it changed over time, and scraped a different HTML tag for the thread ID and then joined it to the web address (showthread.php?t=) to create the link I was looking for.